# Making a value equal to another value in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program and am trying to calculate someones TDEE. The equation does not vary between each gender. To calculate the TDEE you take their activity factor and BMR and multiply it which I know how to do but the activity factor is what varies and is what I need help on. O need to know how I would put "If acLevel1 is equal to 0, then the activity factor is 1.0" into java? But I also need to know how I would change that if it was a female inputting the data because the activity factor varies between gender. I have most of the code written but just need help on that small bit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TDEE
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner TDEE = new Scanner(System.in);
char gender;
char acLevel;
double TDEEReal;

System.out.println("Enter your First and Last name: ");
String TDEE1 = TDEE.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter your Basal Metabolic Rate: ");
double TDEE2 = TDEE.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter your gender (M/F): ");
String gender1 = TDEE.nextLine();
gender = gender1.charAt(0);
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Select your activity level");
System.out.println("[0] Resting(Sleeping, Reclining");
System.out.println("[1] Sedentary(Minimal Activity");
System.out.println("[2] Light(Sitting, Standing)");
System.out.println("[3] Moderate(Light manual labor, Dancing, Riding a bike)");
System.out.println("[4] Very Active(Team sports, Hard manual labor)");
System.out.println("[5] Extremely Active(Full time athlete, Heavy manual labor)");
System.out.println();

System.out.print("Enter the number corresponding to your activity level: ");
String acLevel1 = TDEE.nextLine();
acLevel = acLevel1.charAt(0);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: and what is the problem in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that acLevel1 is a string so you can't use it the way you want to. I would change acLevel1 to an int and change it to nextInt.

Then use if else statement that naresh wrote

```
     if (acLevel == 0) {
         activityFactor = 1.0;
     }
```

Comment: Should that be `acLevel == '0'`?

Comment: Also you _can_ still evaluate a String with .equals method: `if ("0".equals(acLevel1)) {}`.

Comment: Yes but thats not using the boolean == for the if statement.

Comment: Kevin, it would be '0' if he was trying to find the char 0, but I believe he's trying to find the index of 0.

Comment: @Mercifies We're talking about different things. Your code says `acLevel` but you said use `acLevel1` as a string and I assumed that `acLevel` was still the (character) first digit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, I forgot to put into the question(I just edited it)the activity factor varies between gender so how would I change that according to gender?

Comment: @NateLance does the activity factor have a different number for different gender?

Answer (score 0):

[No rudeness intended] Ever heard about conditional statements? If.. else..?

```
if (acLevel1 == 0)
{
    activityFactor = 1.0
}
```

Comment: I have and there is no need to be rude in your first sentence.

Comment: Not quite.  acLevel1 is a String, comparing it to an int literal is not going to work. AcLevel is a char, so if(acLevel == '0').  Also no need to be so snarky, we've all had brain farts.

Comment: I'm not being snarky Kevin. I'm saying he doesn;t have to be rude when all I am doing is asking a simple java question, so I can learn how to do it right. And how is my question not error free? I told you guys all the info you need to know to help me be able to learn how to do it.

Comment: @NateLance I was talking to naresh. Cheers.

Comment: To me it looked like you were being rude, I am sorry for coming to that conclusion right off the bat. Thank you for helping me and I have heard of them and I know how to use them, I just didn't know if thats what I would use to make this equation.

Comment: @NateLance : i think kevinsa5's comment was addressed to me

Comment: Sorry again Kevin. I have a tendency to jump to conclusions.

Comment: @NateLance so u jumped to conclusion that i was rude.. :D

Comment: Yes, sorry, it looked that way to me.

Comment: I understand you were not trying to be rude, but giving your information as a question is a bad idea as it makes it seem as if he should already have known it, it is easier (*safer*) to simply relay the intended information

Comment: if it's a char and you need an int... `Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(yourChar))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement for each of the conditions, once you've followed Mercifies' advice on using the .nextInt() method.